# i have taken troubles with gui in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I don`t write very well English, sorry if you can`t understand me very well.
I did my gui and everything was good. But, when i inserted numbers to calculate results. An error appearded:Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)GUIDEHARDYCROSS('CALCULAR_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.

here is my code.

```
function CALCULAR_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
Q=str2num(get(handles.Q,'string'));
L=str2num(get(handles.L,'sting'));
D=str2num(get(handles.D,'string'));
f=str2num(get(handles.f,'string'));
g=9.81;
Q1=Q(1,1);
D1=D(1,1);
L1=L(1,1);
A1=(pi*D1^2)/4;
Q2=Q(1,2);
D2=D(1,2);
L2=L(1,2);
A2=(pi*D2^2)/4;
Q3=Q(1,3);
D3=D(1,3);
L3=L(1,3);
A3=(pi*D3^2)/4;
Q4=Q(1,4);
D4=D(1,4);
L4=L(1,4);
A4=(pi*D4^2)/4;
Q5=Q(1,5);
D5=D(1,5);
L5=L(1,5);
A5=(pi*D5^2)/4;
Q6=Q(1,6);
D6=D(1,6);
L6=L(1,6);
A6=(pi*D6^2)/4;
Q7=Q(1,7);
D7=D(1,7);
L7=L(1,7);
A7=(pi*D7^2)/4;
Q8=Q(1,8);
D8=D(1,8);
L8=L(1,9);
A8=(pi*D8^2)/4;
Q9=Q(1,9);
D9=D(1,9);
L9=L(1,9);
A9=(pi*D9^2)/4;
Q10=Q(1,10);
D10=D(1,10);
L10=L(1,10);
A10=(pi*D10^2)/4;
%hf PARA MALLAS

%MALLA 1 
Q1_1=-Q1;
K1_1=(f*L1)/(2*g*D1*A1^2);
hf1_1=-(Q1_1^2)*K1_1;
hf1_Q1_1=abs(hf1_1/Q1_1);
Q2_1=Q2;
K2_1=(f*L2)/(2*g*D2*A2^2);
hf2_1=(Q2_1^2)*K2_1;
hf2_Q2_1=abs(hf2_1/Q2_1);
Q3_1=-Q3;
K3_1=(f*L3)/(2*g*D3*A3^2);
hf3_1=-(Q3_1^2)*K3_1;
hf3_Q3_1=abs(hf3_1/Q3_1);
Q4_1=-Q4;
K4_1=(f*L4)/(2*g*D4*A4^2);
hf4_1=-(Q4_1^2)*K4_1;
hf4_Q4_1=abs(hf4_1/Q4_1);

%MALLA 2
Q3_2=Q3;
K3_2=(f*L3)/(2*g*D3*A3^2);
hf3_2=(Q3_2^2)*K3_1;
hf3_Q3_2=abs(hf3_2/Q3_2);
Q5_2=-Q5;
K5_2=(f*L5)/(2*g*D5*A5^2);
hf5_2=-(Q5_2^2)*K5_2;
hf5_Q5_2=abs(hf5_2/Q5_2);
Q6_2=-Q6;
K6_2=(f*L6)/(2*g*D6*A6^2);
hf6_2=-(Q6_2^2)*K6_2;
hf6_Q6_2=abs(hf6_2/Q6_2);
Q7_2=Q7;
K7_2=(f*L7)/(2*g*D7*A7^2);
hf7_2=(Q7_2^2)*K7_2;
hf7_Q7_2=abs(hf7_2/Q7_2);

%MALLA 3
Q4_3=Q4;
K4_3=(f*L4)/(2*g*D4*A4^2);
hf4_3=(Q4_3^2)*K4_3;
hf4_Q4_3=abs(hf4_3/Q4_3);
Q7_3=-Q7;
K7_3=(f*L7)/(2*g*D7*A7^2);
hf7_3=-(Q7_3^2)*K7_3;
hf7_Q7_3=abs(hf7_3/Q7_3);
Q8_3=-Q8;
K8_3=(f*L8)/(2*g*D8*A8^2);
hf8_3=-(Q8_3^2)*K8_3;
hf8_Q8_3=abs(hf8_3/Q8_3);
Q9_3=Q9;
K9_3=(f*L9)/(2*g*D9*A9^2);
hf9_3=(Q9_3^2)*K9_3;
hf9_Q9_3=abs(hf9_3/Q9_3);
Q10_3=Q10;
K10_3=(f*L10)/(2*g*D2_1=Q2;
K2_1=(f*L2)/(2*g*D2*A2^2);
hf2_1=(Q2_1^2)*K2_1;
hf2_Q2_1=abs(hf2_1/Q2_1);
Q3_1=-Q3;
K3_1=(f*L3)/(2*g*D3*A3^2);
hf3_1=-(Q3_1^2)*K3_1;
hf3_Q3_1=abs(hf3_1/Q3_1);
Q4_1=-Q4;
K4_1=(f*L4)/(2*g*D4*A4^2);
hf4_1=-(Q4_1^2)*K4_1;
hf4_Q4_1=abs(hf4_1/Q4_1);

%MALLA 2
Q3_2=Q3;
K3_2=(f*L3)/(2*g*D3*A3^2);
hf3_2=(Q3_2^2)*K3_1;
hf3_Q3_2=abs(hf3_2/Q3_2);
Q5_2=-Q5;
K5_2=(f*L5)/(2*g*D5*A5^2);
hf5_2=-(Q5_2^2)*K5_2;
hf5_Q5_2=abs(hf5_2/Q5_2);
Q6_2=-Q6;
K6_2=(f*L6)/(2*g*D6*A6^2);
hf6_2=-(Q6_2^2)*K6_2;
hf6_Q6_2=abs(hf6_2/Q6_2);
Q7_2=Q7;
K7_2=(f*L7)/(2*g*D7*A7^2);
hf7_2=(Q7_2^2)*K7_2;
hf7_Q7_2=abs(hf7_2/Q7_2);

%MALLA 3
Q4_3=Q4;
K4_3=(f*L4)/(2*g*D4*A4^2);
hf4_3=(Q4_3^2)*K4_3;
hf4_Q4_3=abs(hf4_3/Q4_3);
Q7_3=-Q7;
K7_3=(f*L7)/(2*g*D7*A7^2);
hf7_3=-(Q7_3^2)*K7_3;
hf7_Q7_3=abs(hf7_3/Q7_3);
Q8_3=-Q8;
K8_3=(f*L8)/(2*g*D8*A8^2);
hf8_3=-(Q8_3^2)*K8_3;
hf8_Q8_3=abs(hf8_3/Q8_3);
Q9_3=Q9;
K9_3=(f*L9)/(2*g*D9*A9^2);
hf9_3=(Q9_3^2)*K9_3;
hf9_Q9_3=abs(hf9_3/Q9_3);
Q10_3=Q10;
K10_3=(f*L10)/(2*g*D10*A10^2);
hf10_3=(Q10_3^2)*K10_3;
hf10_Q10_3=abs(hf10_3/Q10_3);

%errores para cada malla
%MALLA 1
DELTAQ_1=-(hf1_1+hf2_1+hf3_1+hf4_1)/(2*(hf1_Q1_1+hf2_Q2_1+hf3_Q3_1+hf4_Q4_1));
SUMAQ_1=(Q1_1+Q2_1+Q3_1+Q4_1);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_1=abs(100*DELTAQ_1/SUMAQ_1);

%MALLA 2
DELTAQ_2=-(hf3_2+hf5_2+hf6_2+hf7_2)/(2*(hf3_Q3_2+hf5_Q5_2+hf6_Q6_2+hf7_Q7_2));
SUMAQ_2=(Q3_2+Q5_2+Q6_2+Q7_2);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_2=abs(100*DELTAQ_2/SUMAQ_2);

%MALLA 3
DELTAQ_3=-(hf4_3+hf7_3+hf8_3+hf9_3+hf10_3)/(2*(hf4_Q4_3+hf7_Q7_3+hf8_Q8_3+hf9_Q9_3+hf10_Q10_3));
SUMAQ_3=(Q4_3+Q7_3+Q8_3+Q9_3+Q10_3);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_3=abs(100*DELTAQ_3/SUMAQ_3);

while ERRORPORCENTUAL_1&ERRORPORCENTUAL_2&ERRORPORCENTUAL_3>1,
Q1_1F=Q1_1+DELTAQ_1;
Q1_1=Q1_1F;
hf1_1F=-(Q1_1F^2)*K1_1;
hf1_Q1_1F=abs(hf1_1F/Q1_1F);
Q2_1F=Q2_1+DELTAQ_1;
Q2_1=Q2_1F;
hf2_1F=(Q2_1F^2)*K2_1;
hf2_Q2_1F=abs(hf2_1F/Q2_1F);
Q3_1F=Q3_1+DELTAQ_1-DELTAQ_2;
Q3_1=Q3_1F;
hf3_1F=-(Q3_1F^2)*K3_1;
hf3_Q3_1F=abs(hf3_1F/Q3_1F);
Q4_1F=Q4_1+DELTAQ_1-DELTAQ_3;
Q4_1=Q4_1F;
hf4_1F=-(Q4_1F^2)*K4_1;
hf4_Q4_1F=abs(hf4_1F/Q4_1F);
Q3_2F=Q3_2+DELTAQ_2-DELTAQ_1;
Q3_2=Q3_2F;
hf3_2F=(Q3_2F^2)*K3_1;
hf3_Q3_2F=abs(hf3_2F/Q3_2F);
Q5_2F=Q5_2+DELTAQ_2;
Q5_2=Q5_2F;
hf5_2F=-(Q5_2F^2)*K5_2;
hf5_Q5_2F=abs(hf5_2F/Q5_2F);
Q6_2F=Q6_2+DELTAQ_2;
Q6_2=Q6_2F;
hf6_2F=-(Q6_2F^2)*K6_2;
hf6_Q6_2F=abs(hf6_2F/Q6_2F);
Q7_2F=Q7_2+DELTAQ_2-DELTAQ_3;
Q7_2=Q7_2F;
hf7_2F=(Q7_2F^2)*K7_2;
hf7_Q7_2F=abs(hf7_2F/Q7_2F);
Q4_3F=Q4_3+DELTAQ_3-DELTAQ_1;
Q4_3=Q4_3F;
hf4_3F=(Q4_3F^2)*K4_3;
hf4_Q4_3F=abs(hf4_3F/Q4_3F);
Q7_3F=Q7_3+DELTAQ_3-DELTAQ_2;
Q7_3=Q7_3F;
hf7_3F=-(Q7_3F^2)*K7_3;
hf7_Q7_3F=abs(hf7_3F/Q7_3F);
Q8_3F=Q8_3+DELTAQ_3;
Q8_3=Q8_3F;
hf8_3F=-(Q8_3F^2)*K8_3;
hf8_Q8_3F=abs(hf8_3F/Q8_3F);
Q9_3F=Q9_3+DELTAQ_3;
Q9_3=Q9_3F;
hf9_3F=(Q9_3F^2)*K9_3;
hf9_Q9_3F=abs(hf9_3F/Q9_3F);
Q10_3F=Q10_3+DELTAQ_3;
Q10_3=Q10_3F;
hf10_3F=(Q10_3F^2)*K10_3;
hf10_Q10_3F=abs(hf10_3F/Q10_3F);
DELTAQ_1F=-(hf1_1F+hf2_1F+hf3_1F+hf4_1F)/(2*(hf1_Q1_1F+hf2_Q2_1F+hf3_Q3_1F+hf4_Q4_1F));
DELTAQ_1=DELTAQ_1F;
SUMAQ_1F=(Q1_1F+Q2_1F+Q3_1F+Q4_1F);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_1F=abs(100*DELTAQ_1F/SUMAQ_1F);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_1=ERRORPORCENTUAL_1F;
DELTAQ_2F=-(hf3_2F+hf5_2F+hf6_2F+hf7_2F)/(2*(hf3_Q3_2F+hf5_Q5_2F+hf6_Q6_2F+hf7_Q7_2F));
DELTAQ_2=DELTAQ_2F;
SUMAQ_2F=(Q3_2F+Q5_2F+Q6_2F+Q7_2F);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_2F=abs(100*DELTAQ_2F/SUMAQ_2F);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_2=ERRORPORCENTUAL_2F;
DELTAQ_3F=-(hf4_3F+hf7_3F+hf8_3F+hf9_3F+hf10_3F)/(2*(hf4_Q4_3F+hf7_Q7_3F+hf8_Q8_3F+hf9_Q9_3F+hf10_Q10_3F));
DELTAQ_3=DELTAQ_3F;
SUMAQ_3F=(Q4_3F+Q7_3F+Q8_3F+Q9_3F+Q10_3F);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_3F=abs(100*DELTAQ_3F/SUMAQ_3F);
ERRORPORCENTUAL_3=ERRORPORCENTUAL_3F;
end
QFINAL=[abs(Q1_1F) abs(Q2_1F) abs(Q3_1F) abs(Q4_1F) abs(Q5_2F) abs(Q6_2F) abs(Q7_2F) abs(Q8_3F) abs(Q9_3F) abs(Q10_3F)]
set(handles.CAUDALESFINALES,'string',num2str(QFINAL));
set(handles.ERROR1,'string',num2string(ERRORPORCENTUAL_1));
set(handles.ERROR2,'string',num2string(ERRORPORCENTUAL_2));
set(handles.ERROR3,'string',num2string(ERRORPORCENTUAL_3));
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* error message.

Comment: Here is [how to write a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you break down your code into a minimal code that allows to reproduce the error? You should add the full error message and it would certainly help to know what this code should do, as it's not very readable.